# Creating Facebook Website Audiences Returning JSON Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to write a node.js script to create a set of Facebook audiences based on URL structure, but I'm getting the below error and I can't seem to identify what is wrong with the JSON I'm sending:

Error I'm getting back: `FacebookRequestError: Invalid rule JSON format: Invalid rule JSON format.`

It seems that the 'rule' property of the 'params' object is somehow invalid, but I can't identify what is wrong with it. I even tried copying [their example from the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences-api/websites#) and it gave the same error. I also pasted the JSON into [the API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and the editor there indicated valid JSON, but the API response was the same.

[api explorer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5cCj.png)

After reading [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289544/create-facebook-custom-audience-for-website-traffic), I tried a bunch of variations using single vs double-quotes, JSON.stringifying the whole thing, part of it, none of it, etc... I'm hoping fresh eyes might catch it.

My Code:

```
"use strict";
const bizSdk = require("facebook-nodejs-business-sdk");
const AdAccount = bizSdk.AdAccount;
const CustomAudience = bizSdk.CustomAudience;

const access_token = "REDACTED";
const app_secret = "REDACTED";
const app_id = "REDACTED";
const id = "act_REDACTED";
const pixelID = "REDACTED";
const api = bizSdk.FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token);
const showDebugingInfo = true; // Setting this to true shows more debugging info.
if (showDebugingInfo) {
    api.setDebug(true);
}

const logApiCallResult = (apiCallName, data) => {
    console.log(apiCallName);
    if (showDebugingInfo) {
        console.log("Data:" + JSON.stringify(data));
    }
};

let fields, params;
fields = [
];
params = {
    "name": "Website - Viewed Product - Corrugated Containers - 180 days",
    "rule": {
        "inclusions": {
            "operator": "or",
                "rules": {
                "inclusions": {
                    "operator": "or",
                        "rules": [
                            {
                                "event_sources": [
                                    {
                                        "id": pixelID,
                                        "type": "pixel"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "retention_seconds": 8400,
                                "filter": {
                                    "operator": "and",
                                    "filters": [
                                        {
                                            "field": "url",
                                            "operator": "i_contains",
                                            "value": "/products/corrugated-containers"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "retention_days": "180",
    "prefill": "1"
};
const customaudiences = (new AdAccount(id)).createCustomAudience(
    fields,
    params
);
logApiCallResult("customaudiences api call complete.", customaudiences);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I had accidentally nested a rules object within a rules object somehow! I fixed that and it created the audience without throwing an error...now I can't *see* the audience definition in Facebook's interface to check that it's correct, but that's a completely different topic.

I changed...

```
params = {
    "name": "Website - Viewed Product - Corrugated Containers - 180 days",
    "rule": {
        "inclusions": {
            "operator": "or",
                "rules": {
                "inclusions": {
                    "operator": "or",
                        "rules": [
                            {
                                "event_sources": [
                                    {
                                        "id": pixelID,
                                        "type": "pixel"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "retention_seconds": 8400,
                                "filter": {
                                    "operator": "and",
                                    "filters": [
                                        {
                                            "field": "url",
                                            "operator": "i_contains",
                                            "value": "/products/corrugated-containers"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "retention_days": "180",
    "prefill": "1"
};
```

to

```
params = {
    "name": "Website - Viewed Product - Corrugated Containers - 180 days",
    "rule": {
        'inclusions': {
            'operator': 'or',
            'rules': [{
                'event_sources': [{
                    'id': pixelID,
                    'type': 'pixel'
                }],
                'retention_seconds': retention_seconds,
                'filter': {
                    'operator': 'and',
                    'filters': [{
                        'field': 'url',
                        'operator': 'i_contains',
                        'value': '/products/corrugated-containers'
                    }]
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "retention_days": retention_days,
    "prefill": "1"
};
```

Comment: A little late to the question, but I had a similar problem, even the example in the official docs didn't work, and your answer helped me! My problem was that "event_sources" field is supposed to be an array as in your example, and the official docs shows it as an JSON object/dictionary. If anyone finds this question googling the problem (as my case), I hope this comment helps.